# Angular2 DI - initializing multiple different instances in the same constructor

Tags: dependency-injection, typescript, angular

I have an Angular2 DI question. Say I have a `TestService` and I want to use 2 different instances of this service inside the same component. If I simply add a provider to the component and I add the 2 instances to the constructor I end up with the same service instance. For example:

**TestService**

```
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";

@Injectable()
export class TestService {

    public id: number = Math.random();

    public toString(): string {
        return "Id: " + this.id;
    }
}
```

**Test component**

```
import {Component, Input, OnInit} from "@angular/core";
import {TestService} from "../../services/test.service";

@Component({
    providers: [TestService]
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private _testService1: TestService, private _testService2: TestService) { };

    ngOnInit() {
        console.log("AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA", this._testService1.toString());
        console.log("BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB", this._testService2.toString());
    }
}
```

**Result in console**

```
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA Id: 0.24242492129168425
BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB Id: 0.24242492129168425
```

Can someone pls tell me if there's a way to use Angular2's DI mechanism to inject multiple different instances of a service within the same component or should I just drop the DI for this particular case and create my instances manually with a manual constructor?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can inject a factory that returns a new instance every time you call it:

```
@NgModule({
   providers: [{
      provide: 'testService', 
      useFactory: (/* TestService deps here like `http`*/) => 
        (/* params */) => new TestService(/* http */), 
      deps: [/* TestService deps here like `Http`*/ ]
    }]
})


@Component(...)
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(@Inject('testService') private _testServiceFactory) { };

    ngOnInit() {
        console.log("AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA", this._testServiceFactory( /* params */).toString());
        console.log("BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB", this._testServiceFactory().toString());
    }
}
```

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/aWjg8O7CjGMR1vt0y9wr?p=preview)
(check the output in the browser console when you click the button)

Comment: It's simply not doing the work. If you inject with useFactory, the factory will be used only once for injecting into _testServiceFactory. But this snippet will not going to work anyway, as you do not have type for the constructor argument, angular can't know what to inject.

Comment: @TimKachko thanks a lot for your valuable feedback! I updated my answer. You are right, about the type. I changed it to use a string key instead with `@Inject()`. The factory will work though. Perhaps I could make it more obvious in the code, but the factory is a function that returns a function, therefore DI will keep an instance of the returned function and pass it to every class that injects `'testService'`, and because a function is passed to the constructor that returns a `new TestService()` every time it is called, this will work.

Comment: Let you just try to get work it in the Plucker you'll see what I mean. the useFactory will inject TestService, not a factory method which you can use to create the TestService.

Comment: Plunker doesn't work well with my Chrome version since a while :-/. Did you see the `useFactory: (...) => (...) => new TestService()` (double `() =>`) where the value returned by the factory is a factory function?

Comment: Correct. This function engages by Angular automatically before construction of the TestComponent to inject the new TestService in the component.

Comment: No, Di calls the factory and passes the return value to the constructor. The return value is again a function, therefore the inner function will be passed to the constructor and can be called there.

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html see example here

Comment: it has only one `()=>` and therefore returns a class instance, while my example (double `()=>`)returns a function

Comment: I added a Plunker.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, what about memory leaks? Previous instances seem to be kept for the whole application life.

Comment: No idea why you think that would be the case. If you don't hold a reference to the class yourself, the garbage collector will collect it.

Answer (score 13):

Given that there is finite amount of instances, the straightforward way may be:

```
@Component({
    providers: [
        { provide: 'TestService1', useClass: TestService },
        { provide: 'TestService2', useClass: TestService }
    ]
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(
        @Inject('TestService1') private _testService1: TestService,
        @Inject('TestService2') private _testService2: TestService
    ) {}
    ...
}
```

Or `OpaqueToken` counterpart to avoid overriding services with the same string identifier:

```
export const TestService1 = new OpaqueToken;
export const TestService2 = new OpaqueToken;

...
providers: [
    { provide: TestService1, useClass: TestService },
    { provide: TestService2, useClass: TestService }
]
...
constructor(
    @Inject(TestService1) private _testService1: TestService,
    @Inject(TestService2) private _testService2: TestService
) {}
```

It doesn't hurt DI in `TestService` constructor. And keeps the testability of `TestComponent` on par, both service instances can be mocked independently.

Comment: Great answer. To complete, I would say OpaqueToken should also be used instead of the strings to avoid naming collisions: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/OpaqueToken-class.html

Comment: @CharlesHETIER Thanks, string identifiers were used here for brevity, but it doesn't hurt to mention that OpaqueToken can be used as well.

Answer (score 2):

I would create a static method that returns new instance in the service, and inject it only one through DI in component. Something like:

```
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";

@Injectable()
export class TestService {

    public id: number = Math.random();

    public toString(): string {
        return "Id: " + this.id;
    }
    static init() {
      return new TestService();
    }
}
```

then in component:

```
import {Component, Input, OnInit} from "@angular/core";
import {TestService} from "../../services/test.service";

@Component({
    providers: [TestService]
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {
    _testService1: TestService;
    _testService2: TestService;

    constructor(_testFactory: TestService) { 
       this._testService1 = _testFactory.init();
       this._testService2 = _testFactory.init();
    };

    ngOnInit() {
        console.log("AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA", this._testService1.toString());
        console.log("BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB", this._testService2.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: This also fits the coding style from the Angular 2 team's docs.

Comment: The thing is where do you store these two instances in case other components need them.