# Angular2: How to inject two instances of the same service into multiple components?

Tags: angular, angular2-services, angular2-providers

Suppose that I have an Angular Service that looks like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class Clipboard {

    constructor(private multiple: Multiple, private di:DI, private injected:Injected, private things: Things){}

    // The clipboard has local state: 
    private isCut: boolean;
    private toPaste: Hero;

    cut(hero: Hero){
        this.isCut = true;
        this.toPaste = hero;
    }

    copy(hero: Hero){
        this.isCut = false;
        this.toPaste = hero;
    }

    paste(locaction: Location){
        // Lots of really complex logic
    }

    canPaste(potentialLocation: Location){
        // Lots of really complex logic
    }

}
```

Currently I have several components that uses the Clipboard Service.

When you right click on a hero you can copy/cut them.  Later, in the same component or a different component, you can paste the hero.  Something like this:

```
@Component({
    ...
})
export class HeroTable {

    constructor(private clipboard: Clipboard){}

    cutHero(hero: Hero): void {
        this.clipboard.cut(hero);
    }
}
```

I now want to add drag and drop to my components.  Interestingly, the `canPaste`, `paste`, `cut` and `copy` methods are identical for drag and drop, however I need to use a separate instance of the clipboard to prevent the following scenario:

1. User cuts 'Batman'
2. User drags & drops 'Superman' to a new location
3. User attempts to paste 'Batman' but unfortunately the clipboard has been polluted by the drag-n-drop.

I could create a new class called `DragDrop` that extends the Clipboard:

```
@Injectable()
export class DragDrop extends Clipboard{

    // Drag and Drop behaves identically to the Clipboard.  Please
    // don't override any behaviour here.  This class is a hack to 
    // get a second injectable instance of Clipboard.

}
```

This allows me to update the HeroTable like this: j

```
@Component({
    ...
})
export class HeroTable {

    constructor(private clipboard: Clipboard, private dragDrop: DragDrop){}

    cutHero(hero: Hero): void {
        this.clipboard.cut(hero);
    }

    dragHer(hero: Hero): void {
        this.dragDrop.cut(hero);
    }
}
```

This also allows me to use the two instances of the Clipboard in another component and tell which is which.  I need to make sure that all components know which Clipboard should be used for Cut/Paste and which should be used for drag/drop.

Unfortunatly, this solution feels like a hack.  Is there an Angular blessed way to do this?

---

*I found this question: [Angular2: How to use multiple instances of same Service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38482357/angular2-how-to-use-multiple-instances-of-same-service) which seems very similar, however I am hoping that given the details that I am providing, I may get slightly different responses.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are not so many ways to do this. I believe they are covered in the cited question and also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38213995/angular2-di-initializing-multiple-different-instances-in-the-same-constructor/38214876#38214876).

For `Clipboard` injectable class without dependencies, it is

```
...
// NgModule
providers: [
  { provide: Clipboard, useValue: Clipboard }
]
```

and

```
export class HeroTable {
    private clipboard: Clipboard;
    private dragDrop: Clipboard;

    constructor(Clipboard: Clipboard){
      this.clipboard = new Clipboard;
      this.dragDrop = new Clipboard;
    }
    ...
}
```

For `Clipboard` injectable class with dependencies, it is

```
@Injectable()
class DragDropClipboard {}

...
// NgModule
providers: [
  Clipboard,
  { provide: DragDropClipboard, useClass: Clipboard }
]
```

and

```
export class HeroTable {
    constructor(private clipboard: Clipboard, private dragDrop: DragDropClipboard) {}
    ...
}
```

There's nothing wrong with

```
@Injectable()
class DragDropClipboard extends Clipboard {}
```

There should be a placeholder for the second provider any way, at least the typing will be correct in this case, but it will likely create more verbose output.

Comment: Agreed.  Although there is a fine line between simplifying your code to turn it into something small and removing important info.

Comment: That's true, writing a good question requires the one to know a half of the answer. TL;DR: I believe that `class DragDropClipboard extends Clipboard {}` is best option here because it gives you type safety and still allows to use `dragDrop: DragDropClipboard` type annotation for DI. There's no typescript tag on the question but I assume that it is so; the 'blessed way' could be different for JS and Babel.