# Angular 4-5 HttpClientModule display data

Tags: angular, typescript

With HttpModule I used this code to get data from Express.js REST API:

```
getArticles() {
  this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/api/articles')
    .map(res => res.json()).subscribe(res => this.articles = res);
}
```

After that I would display the result in the template using binding.

Now, with HttpClientModule, I can't figure out how to do that. The documentation suggests using something like

```
this.httpClient.get('http://localhost:3000/api/articles')
  .subscribe(data => { this.results = data['results']; });
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HttpClientModule` works *almost* the same as the older `HttpModule`. The default `responseType` for `HttpClient` is `json`, so you would skip the step of converting your response to `json` and instead use your response directly like you did before:

```
this.httpClient.get('http://localhost:3000/api/articles')
    .subscribe(data => this.results = data); // result is passed directly
```

Answer (score 1):

HttpClient works best when you cast the returned data. See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46836992/angular-4-what-is-advantage-of-injecting-httpclient/46838155#46838155) where a complete mini project is setup to show how to get and display data.

Answer (score 1):

this.httpClient.getArticles().subscribe(data => this.results = data);