# How to inject multiple service instances in angular components of same service?

Tags: angular, angular5

How to inject multiple service instances into angular components of the same service?

For example - I have dbService in my code and I want to call this dbService instance two times and init both the services with two different values in the constructor. But When I create two instances in component like

constructor( private db1:dbService, private db2:dBservice ){}

It is basically same instance being injected. How to implement such use case in angular 2+ or later.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2 DI - initializing multiple different instances in the same constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38213995/angular2-di-initializing-multiple-different-instances-in-the-same-constructor)

Answer (score 2):

You can create a method in your service which return you instance of that service. something like this -

```
public static instance: dbService;
public static getInstance(http: Http): dbService {
    if (!dbService.instance) {
        dbService.instance = new dbService(http);
    }
    return dbService.instance;
}
private constructor(public http: Http) {
}
```

**PRIVATE CONSTRUCTOR TO MAKE SURE THAT IT CAN'T BE CALLED FROM OUTSIDE**

Then in your component you can call **getInstance()** method as many times as you want.